# Magento 2 No such entity error during the installation

Tags: magento2, error, installation, no-such-entity-exception

I am installing Magento 2 and got one error and was not able to process further.
Error was in Module "Magento_Catalog" step during the installation.

It shows below,

`In PatchApplier.php line 167:`

```
No Such entity.
```

Does Anyone have an idea about this error?

Comment: Which version you are installing?

Comment: version is 2.3.1

Comment: Check this link may be it will help https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Magento-2-3-3-Install-Error/td-p/408855